# what is the difference between maven-resources-plugin and the project.build.resources tag?

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I am having a difficulty to understand the difference between the `maven-resources-plugin` and the `project.build.resources` tag, in maven.

Both seem to have the same purpose. The different goals of the `maven-resources-plugin` [resources, testResources and copy-resources] can also be achieved using the resources tag as:

```xml
<resources>
  <resource>  
    <directory>src/dir</directory>
    <targetPath>dest/dir</targetPath>
  </resource>  
</resources>

<testResources>
  <testResource>
  <directory>src/test/dir</directory>
  </testResource>
```

And using `<resources>` tag will effectively copy the specified files in source directory to destination directory, similar to `copy-resources` goal of `maven-resources-plugin`.

Then, is there any difference between them?
Will they differ in their functionality in any particular scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) is the one which handles the resources area in your pom.xml file.

The definition of the resources plugin is done in the super pom of maven. You can check which version is used by using:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

Furthermore the [resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) goal of the maven-resources-plugin is related to the resources tag in you pom whereas testResources tag is related to [testResources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/testResources-mojo.html) goal of the maven-resources-plugin.

The copy-resources goal can be used to separetely copying resources etc. to an output folder if needed.

Comment: Thanks! So if I use `<resources>` tag to copy a file from a source directory to destination directory, it is similar to using `maven-resources-plugin` with copy-resources goal, right? Since the maven-resources plugin is responsible for handling resources area in pom.xml.

Comment: It's not only similar it is exactly that you are using the maven-resources-plugin. But in the case resources tag you are using resources goal which is bound to the appropriate phases. See also the docs of the maven-resources-plugin and the resources goal in particular.

Comment: So the difference could only be in the phase? We can specify different phases with maven-resources-plugin, but not with resources tag. I will search for what is the default phase `<resources>` tag work in. Thanks for the help!

Comment: However, In a Project with maven and groovy I had to use plugin instead of tag <resources> to exclude a folder, otherwise it does not work.